# How can I configure ES-Lint to require brace spacing specifically for destructuring

Tags: javascript, eslint

Our team woule like to require spaces within curly-spaces for all uses of ES6 destructuring, and to make them optional for normal object literals.

Our philosophy is that restructuring is fundamentally different than an object literal, and we want our code to visually enforce that.

However, even though it seems that ES-Lint can recognize the use of destructuring as opposed to object literals, there doesn't seem to be any option in the [object-curly-spacing](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-spacing) rule to treat destructuring as special, and I wasn't able to find any other rule that would be specific to object destructuring.

Is there a rule or combination of rules that I'm overlooking?

```js
// ok

const { name, title, role } = props;

const person = {name, title};
```

```js
// ES-Lint error

const {name, title, role} = props;

const person = {name, title};
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently ESlint doesn't have that granularity. Feel free propose a new rule. Here is a [guide by ESlint](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/contributing/new-rules).